# Can anyone explain what is "undefined method `downcase' for :undef:Symbol" please?

Tags: ruby, puppet

Running Puppet on *standalone* mode (for the first time) to install mongodb and using `puppet apply -v node.pp` I'm getting this error:

```
Error: undefined method `downcase' for :undef:Symbol at /etc/puppet/modules/mongodb/manifests/install.pp:12 on node ec2.internal
Wrapped exception:
undefined method `downcase' for :undef:Symbol
Error: undefined method `downcase' for :undef:Symbol at /etc/puppet/modules/mongodb/manifests/install.pp:12 on node ec2.internal
```

I did a quick google-search and nothing came obvious to me. Can anyone please explain what am I missing? I don't think it's anything to do with running Puppet in *standalone* mode. BTW, running Puppet v3.2.1 and Ruby v1.8.7 on Debian wheezy.

This is the simplified version of my *mongodb* module and the *apt* is the standard puppet-modue downloaded from git.

**params.pp:**

```
# == Class: mongodb::params ==
#
class mongodb::params {

    $server_pkg_name = $::operatingsystem ? { 
        Debian  => 'mongodb-10gen',
        Redhat  => 'mongo-10gen-server',
    }   
}
```

**repos.pp:**

```
# == mongodb::repos ==
#
class mongodb::repos {

    if $::operatingsystem == 'Debian' {
        class { 'apt': }
        apt::source { '10gen':
            location    => 'http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit',
            release     => 'dist',
            repos       => '10gen',
            key         => '7F0CEB10',
            key_server  => 'keyserver.ubuntu.com',
            include_src => false;
        }   
    }

    #...... Other operatingsystem .......
}
```

**install.pp:**

```
# == Class: mongodb::install
#
class mongodb::install {

    class { 'mongodb::params': }
    anchor { 'mongodb::install::begin': }
    anchor { 'mongodb::install::end': }

    package { 'mongodb-server':
        name    => "$::mongodb::params::server_pkg_name",
        ensure  => installed,
        require => [ Anchor['mongodb::install::begin'], Class[$::mongodb::repos] ],
        before  => Anchor['mongodb::install::end']
    }   
}
```

**init.pp:**

```
# == Class: mongodb ==
#
class mongodb {
    include mongodb::repos
    include mongodb::install
}
```

**node.pp:**

```
node default {
    class { 'mongodb': }
}
```

Does anyone know what am I missing? Please let me know if any other info you may require. Thanks in advance. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no 19th line in your install.php file but the error basically means you're trying to call `downcase` on something that is a symbol rather than a string. You need to you convert whatever parameter it's getting to a string instead of a symbol, either within the installer itself or within the config file.

Edit: I'm unfamiliar with the gem itself, but I'd also wager that the `:undef` symbol is thrown in there somewhere to replace something which you didn't define in a config file. If this ends up being the case, consider reporting a bug to the gem's maintainer, so that it returns something sane to end-users.

Comment: yes, my fault. I know there is no 19th line in `install.pp` (as it's simplified) but the objection on this line: `require => [ Anchor['mongodb::install::begin'], Class[$::mongodb::repos] ]`. Updated the OP with correct line number. cheers!!

Comment: And... any odds that either of `Anchor['mongodb::install::begin']` or `Class[$::mongodb::repos]` is undefined?

Comment: Looks like I made the noise a bit too early - the problem is with scoping. `Class["$::mongodb::repos"]` fixes the error - the double inverted comma `" "` around the class-name was missing. Cheers!!